# Getting uiimageviews from a mutuable array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am storing all the boards `UIImageViews` into a mutable array, 'brds' (the ones that intersect)

```
for (UIImageView *board in boardImg){
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame, board.frame)) {
        [brds addObject:board];
    }
}
```

Then later I am finding the right board in brds for example at index 1:. and then I try to work with the position of that brds[1]. Why am I not getting the right x and y. It always gives me x = 0 and y = 0 I believe. top left corner.

```
board1 = brds[1];

CGRect frame = image.frame;
frame.origin.x = board1.frame.origin.x;
frame.origin.y = board1.frame.origin.y;
image.frame = frame;
```

Doesn't it store the coordinates when I put the imageview into array?

Comment: In the for loop wihin if, try logging and check what it prints.

Comment: Have you initialized brds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check if your array actually contains data using `NSLog`. it probably might be null and you would have to initialize it before adding objects.

Answer (score 0):

RGRect data structure is not reusable Objective-C objects. It means you cannot modify them. Easiest way is to create new one for your purposes.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(board1.frame.origin.x,
                          board1.frame.origin.y,
                          image.frame.size.width,
                          image.frame.size.height);

image.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not `board1 = brds[1];`
brds isn't a C array, it's a NSArray. Use `board1 = [brds objectAtIndex:1];`

Comment: Thanks tried this, the problem is my addObject. It doesn't even add an object to brds in the first place

Comment: Heh, I totally missed that. Good catch.

Comment: @Donny, the problem is in your intersection query. It doesn't look like anything matches.

Comment: What is the correct way to fill that brds if this doesn't work?

Comment: Needed to declare the array with [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; Its fixed! thanks!